# How to display a "foreign key" value in an array in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, foreach, key

I have a current problem, I tried to search in the documentations and the answers already given in the same site, but none of the answers helped me.

In fact I have a database, and two tables.

-> gpscoordonnee

```
MariaDB [leguideduflaneur]> DESCRIBE gpscoordonnee;
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| Nom_Commerce | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| date         | datetime | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.017 sec)
```

-> marchantpart

```
MariaDB [leguideduflaneur]> DESCRIBE marchantpart;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Nom     | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Adresse | varchar(300) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Tel     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Email   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.016 sec)
```

In the `gpscoordonnee` table, the `Nom_Commerce` field is a foreign Keys of `Name` of the `marchantpart` table.

I want by displaying the `Nom_Commerce` that it displays the contents of `Nom`

AND NOT `1`

I have already tried all these methods but nothing is displayed, not even an error :

```
SELECT n.Nom 
from gpscoordonnee us 
    LEFT JOIN marchantpart ON us.NID = n.Nom
```

OR

```
SELECT gpscoordonnee, marchantpart.Nom AS Nom_Commerce 
FROM gpscoordonnee 
    JOIN marchantpart ON marchantpart.Nom=gpscoordonnee.Nom_Commerce
```

I don't want this :
[Result that displays integers instead of names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc6Lr.png)

But i want this :
[Result with names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieJBI.png)

Comment: `SELECT n.Nom from gpscoordonnee us LEFT JOIN marchantpart ON us.NID = n.Nom` - the `gpscoordonnee` table you have shown us, does not appear to contain a `NID` column. That should be `Nom_Commerce` instead. And of course you do not want to compare this numeric ID with `marchantpart.Nom`- that would be the _name_ already - but you want to compare it to `marchantpart.id`

Comment: So you probably want something like this  `SELECT co.\`date\`, mp.Nom AS Nom_Commerce 
FROM gpscoordonnee co
    JOIN marchantpart mp ON marchantpart.id = gpscoordonnee.Nom_Commerce`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my error.

I use `SELECT Nom FROM gpscoordonnee t1 INNER JOIN marchantpart t2 ON t1.Nom_Commerce=t2.id` and my result is this

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDq2N.png)

Thanks for all the people who help me.